# Multiple index with multiple value in single index

Tags: arrays

I want to create an array that has multiple index and in each index i want to place multiple values in single index 
for example

```
String testArr= new String[65];
testArr[0]= {"1,2,3,4,5,56,6,7,8,9"};
testArr[1]={"11.12,1,14.1,6.43"};
testArr[2]={"13,14,12,64,12.14"};
```

like this  how can i achieve this 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Two Dimensional array

```
String testArr = new String[65][10];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for 2D arrays,

```
String testArr = new String[65][10];
```

now every row have an column of size 10.

http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm